# Unable to use Andy (ver. 47.0.1096) as emulation device in Android studio/VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

my cpu doesn't support ept so HXAM cannot be installed but the third party emulator are working good but unable to run my application in thirt party emulator
[see andy is running but unusable in adroid studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ZHW.png)

ALREADY MENTIONED SOLUTION TRIED

```
adb connect localhost:5555
cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

same error as previous
IN Vs code *the avdmanager is missing  from the sdk* is poping up.